# Sum (non adjacent) rows in R

Tags: r

sorry for this basic question. I searched for 30 mins, but didn't find anything that works for me so I take the risk of asking it!

Imagine a data frame as such

```
X1 X2 X3 X4
 1 12  4  6
 5  4 11  2
 2 19 21  2
```

I want to get the sum of the non adjacent rows - 1 and 3, so have a df like this;

```
X1 X2 X3 X4
 1 12  4  6
 5  4 11  2
 2 19 21  2
 3 31 25  8
```

How can I do this?

I tried all of (original data frame has 19 rows and 66 columns);

```
exampleframe1[20,] <- rbind(exampleframe1[19,] + exampleframe1[16,])
exampleframe1[20,] <- rowsum(exampleframe1[19,], exampleframe1[16,])
exampleframe1[20,] <- exampleframe1[19,] + exampleframe1[16,]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is one way to reframe your question that you want the sum of the odd-numbered rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = c(1,5,2), X2 = c(12,4,19), X3 = c(4,11,21), X4 = c(6,2,2))
```

### Index rows and add:

```
df[4,] <- df[1,] + df[3,]

> df
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1 12  4  6
2  5  4 11  2
3  2 19 21  2
4  3 31 25  8

desired_rows <- seq(1,3,2) # can be c(1,4,16,17,20,...) with no pattern

> df[desired_rows,] # subset desired rows only
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1 12  4  6
3  2 19 21  2

> colSums(df[desired_rows,]) # add desired rows only
 X1 X2 X3 X4 
3 31 25  8

> rbind(df, colSums(df[desired_rows,])) # one-liner to add adjacent rows as desired
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1 12  4  6
2  5  4 11  2
3  2 19 21  2
4  3 31 25  8
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you can simply sum the odd rows like this:

```
rbind(df, colSums(df[seq(1, nrow(df), 2), ]))

#  X1 X2 X3 X4
#1  1 12  4  6
#2  5  4 11  2
#3  2 19 21  2
#4  3 31 25  8
```

#### Sample data

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = c(1, 5, 2), X2 = c(12, 4, 19), 
                 X3 = c(4, 11, 21), X4 = c(6, 2, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tidyverse` approach.

require(tidyverse)

```
  df %>% 
    #To get the index of the rows. 
    rownames_to_column("Index") %>%
    #Creating new variable for even and odd rows
    mutate(rowType = ifelse(as.numeric(Index) %% 2 == 0, "even", "odd")) %>% 
    #Delete the index var as we don't need it anymore. 
    select(-Index) %>%
    #Gather and sum by rowType - even/odd row
    gather(Var, value, -rowType) %>% 
    group_by(rowType) %>% 
    summarise(Total = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Results:

```
  rowType Total
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 even      22.
2 odd       67.
```